# Blocking on readable secondary replica

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2017, isolation-level, blocking

We recently migrated from LogShipping `standby/read-only` setup to Multi Subnet AG setup with readable secondaries.

Generally on old setup we have select queries running for longer duration as the database in question is over 20 TB and has mix of read write workload on primary.

After moving to new setup of AG we have started seeing blocking which i am not able to understand. Why select queries on secondary are blocking other select queries in my readable secondary replica instance, even when the database being queried has `RCSI enabled`?

Below is what i have captured

- Lead blocker is some long running `SELECT` query does not show any
  specific waittype as particular, lets say SPID `129`
- `SPID 129` blocks a session ID `45` ( i am sure this is not a user
  id) for almost 6 hours which is dependent on spid129 and wait type is
  `LCK_M_SCH_M`
- Here comes the problem when this `SPID 45` just blocks all other select
  queries now in that 6 hour duration.

I am not able to understand what is happening. Can someone help me troubleshoot or look in correct direction?

Comment: In your case the session `45` must be a redo task which was doing a schema changing operation (index rebuild, for instance). At the same time the session `129` was running a query which used that index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Queries against read-only secondary replicas implicitly run in snapshot isolation regardless of the session isolation level or RCSI setting. This avoids blocking due to DML changes. Read-only queries still acquire [schema stability locks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/active-secondaries-readable-secondary-replicas-always-on-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver15), which will block DDL operations by redo threads and visa-versa.

> SPID 129 blocks a session ID 45 ( i am sure this is not a user id) for
> almost 6 hours which is dependent on spid129 and wait type is
> LCK_M_SCH_M

In your case, it seems a redo thread is waiting for a schema modification lock but is blocked by a very long-running query/transaction schema stability lock. Other queries are in turn blocked by the redo thread.

Take a look at the `SELECT` query execution plan and duration of the transaction for remediation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still have some questions to understand better. When you say SSL will block DDL operations by REDO, i guess you are referring to DDL ones arising from primary replica? Just want to understand why would this specific SELECT query would block the DML operation when so many others running throughout the day? I will check on exec plan and duration to match blocking

Comment: @Newbie-DBA, yes, it will DDL from the primary the redo is applying to the secondary. The other queries are apparently using different objects and therefore not affected. Check the wait resource in the `sys.dm_exec_requests` DMV to identify the specific resource.

Comment: thanks. If in those select queries i use NOLOCK will it prevent using those schema stability locks or anyway we can avoid these select queries blocking?

Comment: @Newbie-DBA, `NOLOCK` [will not avoid schema stability locks](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207433/how-to-avoid-a-select-query-for-holding-a-sch-s-lock#:~:text=A%20Sch%2DS%20lock%20is,structure%20of%20the%20table%20itself.). These are needed tot prevent the table from being dropped or altered while the query is running.

Comment: This morning i am seeing even simple SELECT Queries blocking other SELECT queries with LCK_M_SCH_S locks on other stability. Why is this the case now? Let me know if i need to open this is a separate question?

Comment: @Newbie-DBA, I would expect a schema modification lock by a redo thread in the blocking chain like your question. If that's not the case, ask a new question.

Comment: thanks. One last question as tables are partitioned. Do you think enabling lock escalation to auto will help here?

Answer (score 2):

I found the same issue that was coming from an ALTER INDEX REBUILD activity.
I solved moving this activity in another time window.