# Bypassing LCK_M_SCH_S lock when requesting partition information

Tags: sql-server

I have code to query partition data.
But when the database creates an index, my query does not work because of the LCK_M_SCH_S lock, although I use the NOLOCK hint for all tables.
Is there any way around this lock or get this data without lock?

```
SELECT DB_NAME() AS DatabaseName
        , OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(p.OBJECT_ID) as TableschemaName
        , OBJECT_NAME(p.OBJECT_ID) AS TableName
        , p.index_id AS 'IndexId'
        , CASE WHEN p.index_id = 0 THEN 'HEAP'
                ELSE i.name
            END AS 'IndexName'
        , p.partition_number AS PartitionNumber
        , prv_left.value AS LowerBoundary
        , prv_right.value AS UpperBoundary
        , ps.name as PartitionScheme
        , pf.name as PartitionFunction
        , c.name AS [Partitioning Column]
        , TYPE_NAME(c.user_type_id) AS [Column Type]
        , CASE WHEN fg.name IS NULL THEN ds.name
                ELSE fg.name
            END AS 'FileGroupName'
        , CAST(p.used_page_count * 0.0078125 AS NUMERIC(18,2)) AS UsedPagesMB
        , CAST(p.in_row_data_page_count * 0.0078125 AS NUMERIC(18,2)) AS DataPagesMB
        , CAST(p.reserved_page_count * 0.0078125 AS NUMERIC(18,2)) AS ReservedPagesMB
        , CASE WHEN p.index_id IN (0,1) THEN p.row_count
                ELSE 0
            END AS RowsQuantity
        ,CASE WHEN p.index_id IN (0,1) THEN 'data'
                ELSE 'index'
            END AS Type
    FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats p WITH (NOLOCK)
    JOIN sys.indexes i WITH (NOLOCK) ON i.OBJECT_ID = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
    JOIN sys.data_spaces ds WITH (NOLOCK) ON ds.data_space_id = i.data_space_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.partition_schemes ps WITH (NOLOCK) ON ps.data_space_id = i.data_space_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.partition_functions pf WITH (NOLOCK) ON ps.function_id = pf.function_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.destination_data_spaces dds WITH (NOLOCK) ON dds.partition_scheme_id = ps.data_space_id
                                            AND dds.destination_id = p.partition_number
    LEFT JOIN sys.filegroups fg WITH (NOLOCK)   ON fg.data_space_id = dds.data_space_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.partition_range_values prv_right WITH (NOLOCK) ON prv_right.function_id = ps.function_id
                                                AND prv_right.boundary_id = p.partition_number
    LEFT JOIN sys.partition_range_values prv_left WITH (NOLOCK) ON prv_left.function_id = ps.function_id
                                                AND prv_left.boundary_id = p.partition_number - 1
    LEFT JOIN sys.index_columns ic WITH (NOLOCK) ON ic.[object_id] = i.[object_id]   
                                AND ic.index_id = i.index_id   
                                AND ic.partition_ordinal >= 1 
    LEFT JOIN sys.columns c WITH (NOLOCK) ON p.OBJECT_ID = c.[object_id]   
                            AND ic.column_id = c.column_id  
    WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(p.OBJECT_ID, 'ISMSSHipped') = 0
        AND p.index_id IN (0,1) 
        AND ps.name IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: You might have better luck joining to `sys.objects` and filtering on `is_ms_shipped = 0` rather than using `OBJECTPROPERTY` since those functions often ignore locking semantics.

Comment: @ErikDarling - changed OBJECTPROPERTY  to sys.objects - it didnt help:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In certain editions of SQL Server, you can create an index **"Online"**. This means that the server does not take a `Sch-M` lock until the very end of the process, for a brief period.

You can do this through the SSMS index properties, or using `ONLINE = ON` in T-SQL.

Important things to note about doing this:

- It is only supported in Enterprise and Developer editions.
- You need disk space for the whole index again, then some.
- It may take longer to do the index operation than an offline.
- It may slow down other DML transactions.
- Don't put it inside a long explicit transaction, otherwise the final `Sch-M` lock is still held until the end.

See also [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/guidelines-for-online-index-operations?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: I think this is the solution, but we have the Standard version:)

Answer (score 2):

There is no workaround. This is by design. As per Microsoft documentation:

> Occurs when a task is waiting to acquire a Schema Share lock. See
> Schema Locks for more information.
>
> The SQL Server Database Engine uses schema stability (Sch-S) locks
> when compiling and executing queries. Sch-S locks do not block any
> transactional locks, including exclusive (X) locks. Therefore, other
> transactions, including those with X locks on a table, continue to run
> while a query is being compiled. However, concurrent DDL operations,
> and concurrent DML operations that acquire Sch-M locks, cannot be
> performed on the table.

Here is a repo of what you are seeing and why you are being blocked. I am using the AdventureWorks database [provided by Microsoft](https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/releases/tag/adventureworks) and big tables created using a query written by Adam Machanic.
[enter link description here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2011/10/17/thinking-big-adventure.aspx)

Run this from one of the query windows:

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GO

BEGIN TRAN
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_ProductId_TransactionDate
ON dbo.bigTransactionHistory
(
    ProductId,
    TransactionDate
)
INCLUDE 
(
    Quantity,
    ActualCost
);
GO
--COMMIT TRAN
```

Open a new window and do a select with NOLOCK.

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GO
SELECT 
    *
FROM dbo.bigTransactionHistory WITH (NOLOCK)
```

Now check wait type/blocking and locks held by each session:

```
EXEC sp_whoisactive
@get_locks  = 1
```

You will see that select with NOLOCK is blocked because of LCK_M_SCH_S lock.
[image]

If you see the locks column from the above output and click on the XML you will see that select with NOLOCK is requesting an `Sch-S` (Schema stability lock) lock and is waiting because this lock is not compatible with `LCK_M_SCH_S`.

```
<Database name="AdventureWorks">
  <Locks>
    <Lock request_mode="S" request_status="GRANT" request_count="1" />
  </Locks>
  <Objects>
    <Object name="bigTransactionHistory" schema_name="dbo">
      <Locks>
        <Lock resource_type="OBJECT" request_mode="Sch-S" request_status="WAIT" request_count="1" />
      </Locks>
    </Object>
  </Objects>
</Database>
```

Here is a Q&A [How to avoid a select query for holding a Sch-S lock](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207433/how-to-avoid-a-select-query-for-holding-a-sch-s-lock) where Mike Walsh explains why this is necessary.

General locking information (copied from [here](https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/lck_m_sch_s/)):

- For the complete lock compatibility matrix, see the Books Online page [Lock Compatibility.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms186396(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- For information on the lock hierarchy, see the Books Online page Lock [Granularity and Hierarchies.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms189849(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- For information on some of the lock modes, see the Books Online page [Lock Modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms175519(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).
- For other locking topics, see the Books Online page [Locking in the Database Engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms190615(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: `ONLINE=ON` option should allow a Sch-S lock during the build phase?